# Recurrent pattern to map on Google event pattern

Tags: rfc5545, google-calendar-api

Google implements recurring patterns partly with [rfc 5545](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545).
I need to map on Google situation of repeat event **Yearly, every fourth Wednesday in August** (start time mapping is clear).

Implementation language to describe rule is not important, but if someone can recommend existing solution it would be good if java library is used.

---

More details from rfc 5545 specification:

```
Every Wednesday in August, forever:
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYMONTH=8;BYDAY=WE
```

It provides only partly solution. **Is it can be improved?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
{
  "summary": "Event every fourth Wednesday in August",
  "recurrence": [
    "RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYMONTH=8;BYDAY=4WE;UNTIL=20191228"
  ],
  "start": {
    "dateTime": "2017-08-08T6:00:00",
    "timeZone": "timeZone"
  },
  "end": {
    "dateTime": "2017-08-08T7:00:00",
    "timeZone": "timeZone"
  }
}
```

This will make your even occur every year, 4th Wednesday of August.

Reference:

- [Can I create a Google Calendar event that repeats at every 1st, 3rd and 5th Friday in the month?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/24182)
- [Recurring events](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/concepts/events-calendars#recurring_events)

Hope this helps