# Last workday before date

Tags: google-calendar-api, icalendar

I want to set a monthly recurring event (or reminder) in Google calendar for the last workday (i.e. excluding weekends) before a specific date. For example, if 22 Oct is on Sunday, I want 20 Oct (Friday), but if it's on Tuesday, I want this one.

As a plus, can the holidays be excluded, too?

Answer (score 4):

This would work for the 22nd of every month. `RRULE:FREQ=MONTHLY;WKST=MO;BYMONTHDAY=20,21,22;BYDAY=MO,TU,WE,TH,FR;BYSETPOS=-1`

Comment: This does not seem to work. I tried for the 15th so swapped the values of BYMONTHDAY from 20,21,22 to 13,14,15. Adding it to my calendar for a month where the 15th fell on Sunday resulted in the event being shown on the 12th (Thursday) instead of the 13th.

Comment: If you leave off the BYSETPOS part, however, this works (as long as you keep in mind that DTSTART must be specified in UTC otherwise it could put events on the previous day local time!)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by setting the correct `RRULE` for the recurrence.

You can check this related SO post I've answered for creating a recurring ["Event every fourth Wednesday in August"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43809264/5995040) and this tutorial : [Create a repeating event on last day of each month on Google Calendar](https://www.bggofurther.com/2014/12/create-a-repeating-event-on-last-day-of-each-month-on-google-calendar/) for code implementation reference.

```
{
  "summary": "Event Last Day of the Month",
  "recurrence": [
    "RRULE:FREQ=MONTHLY;BYDAY=MO,TU,WE,TH,FR;BYSETPOS=-1;WKST=MO"
  ],
  "start": {
    "dateTime": "2017-08-31T6:00:00",
    "timeZone": "timeZone"
  },
  "end": {
    "dateTime": "2017-08-31T7:00:00",
    "timeZone": "timeZone"
  }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try to figure it out from your references.